# JavaScript functions and prototypes

Tags: javascript

After reading about prototype in JavaScript, I've created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EX6W9/4/) to test some things about how functions work.

I understand that the prototype of the two functions are not the same. But why are the 'foo' and 'bar' functions the same as they have a different name and they both do different things?

The code:

```
var test1 = function(){
function foo(){
    alert('test1 foo function');
}
}

var test2 = function(){
    function bar(){
        alert('test2 foo function');
    }
}

if (test1.foo === test2.bar) {
    alert("they're the same")
}

if (test1.prototype === test2.prototype){
    alert("they're not the same")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `test1.foo()`?

Comment: You seemed to be confused about function scope, variables within a function are not accessible that way.

Comment: Both are `undefined`.

Comment: @deceze: that has no effect on that, they will both return `undefined`.

Comment: @OneKitten Exactly my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` and `bar` are functions that exist *inside* the function bodies of `test1` and `test2` when they are executing.

They are not properties of `test1` and `test2` and so, `test1.foo` and `test2.bar` are both `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Because both, `test1.foo` and `test2.bar` values are `undefined`. You can see them by outputting like `console.log(test1.foo)` and `console.log(test2.bar)`

I suggest you to output any parameter with which you're going to make a comparison in order to see the differences and guess what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in expression `test1.foo === test2.bar`, they are both undefined, 
you create property of object in wrong way,
check "**javascript: the definitive guide 6th**" for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them return `undefined` since there is no property called `foo` and `bar` and so `undefined == undefined` becomes true, which is why you are getting the alert `alert("they're the same");`